# How to remove certain data frames based on number of columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, environment-variables

I would like to delete only some data frames from the environment. Since I have more than 400 data frames there, I would like to select based on number of columns.

I tried the code below that does not work, however.

```
# Select data tables
dfs <- ls()
dfs <- dfs[grepl(".csv", dfs)]

myfilenames <- list.files(inputdir, pattern = ".csv$")
storage <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=length(myfilenames), ncol=1))

# Filter for 25 columns
for (i in seq_along(dfs)){
  dat <- get(dfs[i])
  if(ncol(dat)!=25){
      storage[i,1] <- dfs[i]
  } 
}

# Delete
todelete <- storage[,1]
rm(todelete)
```

Expected result: only data frames with 25 columns remain in Global environment
Actual result: none is removed

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Does the `todelete` vector contain the values you want? When you do `rm(todelete)` you are deleting that vector, not the variables with the names in the vector. To pass a vector of names to `rm()`, use the `list=` parameter: `rm(list=todelete)`. See the `?rm` help page for details.

Comment: I'm confused throughout the code as to when the strings we're dealing with are file paths or names of environment objects. It's as if the objects are named after the files they're from. Is that the case?

Comment: Thank you, list=todelete does the trick!

Comment: More than 400 data frames in your environment is bad practice. Put them in lists: https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/535931179556691968